# Fallback URL handler for NextJS with getServerSideProps support

Tags: routes, next.js

I have web app based on NextJS 13.x. If has common `getServerSideProps` factory that analyze app state and return redirect/shared props, so any page looks like:

```
import { NextPage } from "next";


import { getServerSidePropsFactory } from "@/utils";


export const getServerSideProps = {
  getServerSideProps: getServerSidePropsFactory(
    "/onboarding"
  ),
};

const OnboardingPage: NextPage<{}> = () => {
  return <OnboardingForm></OnboardingForm>
};

export default OnboardingPage;
```

Now I want to add a fallback handler for ALL urls on the server to handle it with the same `getServerSidePropsFactory`, so if user put wrong url they still be redirected to appropriate place.

I tried to achieve it by overloading `/pages/404.tsx` but it doesn't support `getServerSideProps` - only `getStaticProps` which doesn't provide all required variables to derive context so cannot be used.

Question: is there any way to handle ALL urls on the server unless it is found among existing `/pages` and that support `getServerSideProps` export?